# Is there a way to use 'the beginning of time' in SQL

Tags: sql, date, time

I've done a bit of research around this site and through Google and can't seem to find what I'm looking for, I'm fairly new to SQL so there's a chance I've missed or misunderstood something already but basically, I'm trying to do a report and usually I use

```
where (realdate = '2015-02-28')
```

or

```
datenow BETWEEN '2015-04-01' AND '2015-04-30'
```

Both of these usually serve me well but I'm trying to find out everything from `the beginning of time` until the current date. I haven't been able to find anything to do with this yet, besides a question someone else asked on another side that was sadly, unanswered.

Any help or just a point in the right direction will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres (and DB2 I think) support a datetime literal named `infinity` (and `-infinity`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `<=` operator

```
where (realdate <= '2015-02-28')
```

which means  `evrything to day 2015-02-28`

Comment: Use the `<=` operator to include the specified date in the search.

Comment: @RezaRahmati OP want to from beginning to date so `<` is goog

Comment: @Parado OP wants `from 'the beginning of time' until the current date` so it should be `where (realdate >= '2015-02-28')`

Comment: @RezaRahmati I understand  `until '2015-02-28' ` as `less than '2015-02-28'`

Comment: @RezaRahmati: no it should not. `realdate >= '2015-02-28'` means "*till the **end** of time*"

Answer (score 0):

if you mean by 'the beginning of time' (unspesified date) until current date (unspesified date):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `realdate` <= NOW()
```

but if you can specify the current date:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `realdate` <= DATE('YYYY-MM-DD')
```